# Graphical flicker/error in animation when using scrollviewer in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm building a windows 8 store app using Visual Studio 2013 express and am coding in Xaml/c#.

When I scroll horizontally or just hold my finger on the screen my animation leaks. By leaks I mean flickering triangles appear randomly outside of the grid performing the animation.

Ive tried various settings in the scrollviewer without any luck. when I remove the scrollviewer the animation performs as expected so it appears the problem lies with the scrollviewer perhaps redrawing the elements on the page.

Below is a test app that shows the problem

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.8" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border1">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationX)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border2">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.6" Value="-90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border3">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2.5" Value="90"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3.3" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<ScrollViewer x:Name="MainScroll"  ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
               ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="500" Height="500">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="Red"/>
        <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Purple" >
            <Border.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationY="90"/>
            </Border.Projection>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="Border1" Background="Purple" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Border.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationY="-90"/>
            </Border.Projection>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="Border3" Background="Purple" Grid.Row="1" >
            <Border.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationY="90"/>
            </Border.Projection>
        </Border>
        <Border x:Name="Border2" Background="Purple" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" >
            <Border.Projection>
                <PlaneProjection RotationX="-90"/>
            </Border.Projection>
        </Border>
    </Grid>

        <Grid Width="1000" Background="Blue" Height="300" Margin="50"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += (s, args) =>
            {
                this.Storyboard1.Begin();
            };
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that before when writing OpenGL code on Android. It turns out I had a bug in my code. OpenGL gives all these nasty bugs when you make mistakes, because it is a giant state machine. Sorry, I can't be of more help. But it sounds like you are doing something wrong somewhere (I was). Could you try commenting things out until the problem no longer occurs? Maybe narrowing it down will help.

Comment: Appears it was a driver issue with Surface 2 bah what a pain